# Cloud Formation - can't upload template file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I try and create a stack by uploading a template.
That fails with an error heading that is blank.

I have permissions to create buckets, upload files, create EC2 instances, etc.
I tried switching to my root account even but that didn't help.

I've tried different YAML files and examples but none seem to work.
Without meaningful error messages with actionable items I am stuck.

[image]

[image]

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Metadata": {
        "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
            "213de823-ad0a-4f4c-af04-e3c9e565eef8": {
                "size": {
                    "width": 60,
                    "height": 60
                },
                "position": {
                    "x": 581,
                    "y": 148
                },
                "z": 0
            }
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "EC2I4PJFK": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {},
            "Metadata": {
                "AWS::CloudFormation::Designer": {
                    "id": "213de823-ad0a-4f4c-af04-e3c9e565eef8"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Was the error message literally 'cannot upload this bucket to S3'? I ask because the message doesn't make sense. When you use the CloudFormation console to create a stack and you choose the 'Upload a template file' option, the console uploads your template to an S3 bucket named something like cf-templates-abcdef123456-us-east-1. That's a bucket that was created by CF in your account to store your templates. You should not typically attempt to manage this bucket. That aside, does this problem repo in a different browser or an incognito session?

Comment: Can you take a look at the browser's console / networking tab?
See exactly what is the response from the upload service
If the file managed to upload sucessfully and AWS refuse to allow template creation, maybe it's time to create a support ticket

Comment: Ah! It appears that you are using the CloudFormation Designer. Is that where you are experiencing the error message? Frankly, the designer is not a great way to create templates (it's okay for viewing, but not great for creating).

Comment: No, not designer issue.  See answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## I was in the wrong region

Once I switched to us-east-1 (Virginia) in the management console itself, all these problems went away.  When I switch to another region they return.  The template also refers to resources in us-east-1.  So this explains how to avoid the error, however the poor (even blank) error messages are very unhelpful.  I am still not sure if the other region AMI ref is the issue or whether you just need to be in N. Virginia to run cd.

At one point I had even got the template to execute (though resource created still failed) by using an S3 bucket that I had created for the template file instead of the upload file functionality.  When I used the 'load from S3 bucket' approach it actually uploaded but then failed in stack creation due to the wrong region issue (AMIs for example are region specific).  This just added to the confusion when debugging the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Adding following policy to my role(in your case, it may be a role or a user) worked for me:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cf-template*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: permission s3:PutObject did the trick for me

Comment: This worked for me since the "CloudFormation Full Access" managed policy does not have this in place which is ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

### Resolution

Had the same issue when trying to upload a `template.yml` file I had created. My solution was to create a Public Object in S3 and then copy the Object URL into Cloudformation.

The solution proposed by the author did not help me.

### Debugging

Inspecting the console and http requests didn't lead to much unfortunately.
The request to: `https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/service/upload/uploadSuccess?bucket=cf-templates-jcexs078zt-us-east-1&key=somekey-template.yml&etag=someetag`

Returns a 200.

Request Headers:

```
Host: console.aws.amazon.com
Referer: https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/home?region=us-east-1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: iframe
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36
```

Response Headers:

```
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no store
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Date: Sun, 31 May 2020 00:05:20 GMT
Expires: Sat, 30 May 2020 00:05:20 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: Server
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=47304000; includeSubDomains
Vary: Accept-Encoding,X-Amzn-CDN-Cache,X-Amzn-AX-Treatment,User-Agent
x-amz-rid: {sensitive-info?}
X-CloudFormation-RequestId: 885b8352-3178-4658-8326-b6a696a89579
```

### Expected Behavior

I would expect my file to be uploaded to s3 automatically, and if it fails I would expect a meaningful error message to be returned and displayed.

Answer (score 2):

From AWS Support....

If you're using "Chrome" browser and seeing this issue, please try to clear cookies/browser cache, quit the browser and login again to AWS Console and try to create the stack [1]. Additionally, try after disabling browser extensions. [2]

Workarounds:
- You can try with any other browser and see if the stack creation is successful.
- You can manually upload the template to an S3 bucket and reference the S3 URL while creating the stack.
- You may also use AWS CLI to create the stack.[3]

[1]: Clear Cache and Cookies on Chrome: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

[2]: Manage extensions on Chrome: https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?hl=en

[3]: CLI Command reference to create stack: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/create-stack.html

Comment: The offending extension for me was LastPass

Comment: I have LastPass as well

Comment: I had the same issue, disabled LastPass and all went fine again.

Answer (score 0):

I think to upload the file to s3 and paste the s3 URI is the only workaround right now.